# How can I add a currency field to a content type?

Tags: 7, entities

I would like to have a field that accepts U.S. dollar amount. I installed the module: https://www.drupal.org/project/currency. Structure > content type > I do not see a field type "Currency". I am not sure how I can add a field to accept USD amount.

How can I add the price field to the content type?

Comment: Hi, what do you need it for? If you just need to display some dollar amounts you can create a decimal field and then change display output to have $ prefixed.

Comment: I need it for a real estate site. I like to add a price field for the house value. Currency module I installed might be for a bigger project. I will have to do some research on how to add a decimal field. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using drupal 7 or 8? Ill modify my answer based on which version youre on.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So to add a decimal field.

- edit your content type.
- manage fields
- add new field
- select Decimal from the Field Type dropdown.
- Click the 'Save' button
- Change 'Scale' to 2. These are the cents.
- Click the 'Save field settings' button.
- In the Prefix field add '$'.
- Click the 'Save settings' button

Comment: Thanks. Drupal 7. I did not see number field. I see integer field. I added integer field then widget (decimal > text field) > saved it. Where do I specify 2 decimal places? I also did not understand this part "To prefix a $ to the display value you may need to add a template_preprocess_field and add a #prefix to the field."

Comment: Drupol, I've updated the instructions. I updated the step by step while actually creating my own field.

Comment: I don't have decimal field type. I need to install another module to see decimal field type?

Comment: Nope. It's a default field. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21modules%21number%21number.module/function/number_field_info/7.x Be sure to update drupal core.

Comment: @JapoDomingo What if we want to show the currency symbol depending on the user country? Also, how to show /hr or fixed prices?

Comment: Hi Umair, You can try using https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n for changing the currency. Im not sure what you mean about hr and fixed prices.